# Why I can't inject a class in a test case with dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I am testing my laravel project with dusk.

I am trying to inject a dependency in a test like that :

```
....
class PasswordLostTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    private $passwordResetRepository;
    
    public function __construct(PasswordResetRepository $passwordResetRepository)
    {
        $this->passwordResetRepository = $passwordResetRepository;
    }
.....
```

When I run the test with *php artisan dusk .\tests\Browser\PasswordLostTest.php*, I have this error :

**Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Tests\Browser\PasswordLostTest::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\Workspace\classified-ads-mpa\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestBuilder.php on line 138 and exactly 1 expected in D:\Workspace\classified-ads-mpa\tests\Browser\PasswordLostTest.php:20**

What is the problem ? Is it because I am in a test script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestCases` are not instantiated by the container. Secondly your app is not bootstrapped before setup has been called, the constructor is called first. Making your example technically impossible. Instead use `resolve()` or `app()->make()`, in the setup method to do what you want.

Your app is bootstrapped to the parent test cases setup, so calling         `parent::setUp();` is essential.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->passwordResetRepository = resolve(PasswordResetRepository::class);
}
```

Comment: I have understood, thanks. However, I now have an error in my test case when I try to do `$passwordReset = $this->passwordResetRepository->insert();` **Call to a member function insert() on null**. I am not sure that the class has been instantiated in the setUp....

Comment: The class extends **DuskTestCase**, and not **TestCase**. Perhaps it explains my problem ?

Comment: No, something in the naming is wrong, i thought setup was an internal function but it aint, that is my bad, i edited the answer

Comment: I found the solution. I answered to my question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: isn't that the same just with :void added?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->passwordResetRepository = resolve(PasswordResetRepository::class);
    }
```

**WARNING : the *void* is mandatory. That's why it did not work !**

Many thanks to mrhn who guided me for this problem !